# Entity Framework dataset mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

All of my DAL functions are using `dbContext.Database.SqlQuery` to map stored procedure results in business logic objects.

My application became more complicated and I'm looking for a modern, "up to date" way to handle the following situations. I know that I can achieve this using the low-level ADO.NET component like `SqlDataReader` and map the result manually, but I am sure there is the best way to do so using Entity Framework 6.

To the question: with this command `dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<MyClass>`, I can not handle:

1. The stored procedure that returns 2 result sets
2. Mapping the result set to a complex datatype

Example:

```
public class Order
{
    public Customer customer { get; set; }
    public Items[] items { get; set; }
}
```

Again, I know that I can map it manually or with AutoMapper, but I'm looking for an "up to date" approach based on Entity Framework 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's a way using *[Translate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466384(v=vs.110).aspx)*.

Adapted from the [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj691402(v=vs.113).aspx):

```
    var cmd = dbContext.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[GetAllCustomersAndOrders]";


    dbContext.Database.Connection.Open();
    // Run the sproc 
    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    var Customers= ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext)
        .ObjectContext
        .Translate<Customer>(reader, "Customers", MergeOption.AppendOnly);   

    reader.NextResult();
    var Orders = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db)
        .ObjectContext
        .Translate<Order>(reader, "Orders", MergeOption.AppendOnly);
```

As far as the problem of mapping

> few columns from the result to a 2nd level complex type? for example:
>   SELECT FirstName, LastName, OrderId FROM Orders I want to map it to:
>   public class Order { public Customer customer { get; set; } public int
>   OrderId { get; set; } }

The best would be to use a *CustomerId* inside your *Order* table, referencing a *Customer* table, instead of *FirstName*/*LastName*. It would be a good refactoring, normalizing the database. Otherwise you will not have a real mapping between your objects and your database, since your *Order* object will have a *Customer* property that doesn't exist in your database. In that case, you will have to create a class, e.g. *NormalizedOrder*

```
public class NormalizedOrder { 
   int OrderId { get; set; }; 
   Customer OrderCustomer { get; set; }; 
}
```

And then, after the code above where you retrieve all Orders, do something like

```
 var NormalizedOrders = Orders.Select new Order(){OrderId = e.OrderId, OrderCustomer = new Customer(){FirstName=>e.FirstName,LastName=>e.LastName}};
```

Comment: And how can i map few columns from the result to a 2nd level complex type? for example:

SELECT

FirstName,
LastName,
OrderId

FROM Orders

I want to map it to:

public class Order
{
  public Customer customer { get; set; }
  public int OrderId { get; set; }
}

Comment: can you please help with the above?

Comment: Do you mean you want to create a Customer object inside Order, using FirstName and LastName?

Comment: The best would be to use a CustomerId inside your Order table, referencing a Customer table, instead of FirstName/LastName. It would be a good refactoring, normalizing the database. Otherwise you will not have a real mapping between your objects and your database, since your Order object will have a Customer property that doesn't exist in your database. In that case, You will have to create a class, e.g. *NormalizedOrder*, and then `var NormalizedOrders = Orders.Select new Order(){OrderId = e.OrderId, Customer = new Customer(){FirstName=>e.FirstName,LastName=>e.LastName}};`

Comment: @ Francesco i marked the answer, could you please add that to the original answer so it will be full answer?

Comment: https://www.khalidabuhakmeh.com/entity-framework-6-multiple-result-sets-with-stored-procedures